# Ruby Sequel - How to combine eager graph for association with order and limit, without duplicates

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

Consider these models:

```
class Member < Sequel::Model
  one_to_many :member_integrations

  # columns: [:id, :name]
end

class MemberIntegration < Sequel::Model
  many_to_one :member
  one_to_many :member_integration_fields

    # columns: [:member_id, :name]
end

class MemberIntegrationField < Sequel::Model
  many_to_one :member_integration

  # columns: [:id, :member_integration_id, :name]   
end
```

I need to load paginated members, filter and order them by `MemberIntegrationField#name`

```
members = Member.exclude(name: nil).eager_graph(member_integrations: [:member_integration_fields])
members = members.where(Sequel.ilike(Sequel[:member_integration_fields][:name], '%John%'))
members = members.order(Sequel[:member_integration_fields][:name].desc)
```

All this works but it returns duplicated members and so the pagination does not work.

```
Member.count # 5246

members.limit(50, 0).all.count # 25
members.count # 31473
```

I got the idea of why members are duplicated but I cannot figure how to fetch them properly. Because of that, the pagination gets the wrong total count `31473` and the wrong count of members is fetched `25`.

Would be good to mention that `ilike` must filter the members but in the end, all member integrations for a filtered member should be returned.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can try asking on https://groups.google.com/g/sequel-talk The creator of Sequel hangs out there quite frequently among other helpful folks.